# PostgreSQL Column Index Query Optimization Question

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

Will the following query be optimizable if I create indexes on latitude*69 and longitude*46?

```
select * from locations where abs(latitude*69 - 3036) <= 25
                          and abs(longitude*46 - 8970) <= 25
```

Or must I remove the `abs()` and code it more like:

```
select * from locations where (latitude*69 - 3036) between -25 and 25 
                          and (longitude*46 - 8970) between -25 and 25
```

or the even more simplistic:

```
select * from locations where latitude*69 between 3036-25 and 3036+25 
                          and longitude*46 between 8970-25 and 8970+25
```

Comment: Why don't you just create the index and test it?

Comment: What, and do some actual work? ;)  I can do what you're asking, but if it doesn't optimize it then I have no clue how to change it so that it will optimize.  I couldn't find any docs on the Postgres site discussing what is and isn't optimizable -- can you recommend any resources for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if the query is optimizable with indexes, the easy way is to do what splash says.

Create a GIST INDEX and use EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN VERBOSE before a query to see the execution plan that postgres uses. If you see something like *SCAN SEQ*, then is *not* using the index. If you see a *INDEX SCAN* then *is* using the index for that particular query.

In order to use the indexes over GIS data, you must use functions that use the bounding box of the geom/geog. There are functions in Postgis that make use of bounding boxes to use the indexes, like all the [operators](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/reference.html#Operators),or some functions that use operators inside to filter.

I think that the best query you could make to see if the lonlat is in a box (is that what you are trying to do?) is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM locations
WHERE
    ST_Dwithin(
        'POINT('||(longitude*46)||' '||(latitude*69)||')'::geometry,
        'POINT(8970 3036)'::geometry
    )
```

(not tested, but should work also with indexes)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me how to fish! ;)  If my testing shows that it doesn't optimize it then I have no clue how to change it so that it will optimize.  I couldn't find any docs on the Postgres site discussing what is and isn't optimizable -- can you recommend any resources for this?

Comment: You must read the Postgis docs http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/reference.html
In each function documentation you'll see "notes", some of them say that they will use indexes whenever they are available, like the ST_Dwithin function.

Answer (score 1):

I get the sense from your question that you are looking to find points within a 25 unit box around some point. Any postgres index (GIN, GiST, b-tree, r-tree etc.) will do fine on this query as long as `locations` are only points. If locations include some other geometries (shapes of cell tower reception, delivery route areas, whatever), then you want a GiST r-tree. But a better approach overall, since I get the impression from some other questions that geography is fundamental to what you're working on, is to use [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) or at the very least the [geometry support built into Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-geometry.html). A literal translation of your example would be:

```
select * from locations 
where my_point_column <@ box '((194.4, 43.36),(194.5 43.6))'
```

in Postgres against a column with a geometry type, and the PostGIS version is much the same with a lot of improvements and utilities for all kinds of data.

Comment: By points, do you mean integers?  I'm trying to pin distances down to, say, 25 miles (which is less than a full degree) so fractions of degrees count.  If by points, you mean discrete locations (a single point on the plane of the earth) vs. areas (e.g. a city or state) then you are correct that I am using distance between two points.  I do not want to incur the processing overhead of calculating the most precise distance so I'm using the low-overhead alternative of finding all points in the database within an x-mile box (not circle) around my location.

Comment: A point is just a 2 or 3 dimensional record, like (1,1) in the Cartesian plane, which is 1.414 away from (0,0). It doesn't have to be an integer, (1.414, 1.414) is 2 away from (0,0). Postgres has support for these kinds of geometries (see the link) and for indexes on them. Simple example: say you have points 1 -> (123.4, 56.7), 2 -> (123.4, 67.8), and 3 -> (123.4, 65.4). Index by interleaving powers of 10 in the x,y coordinates: 3-> 10263544 1-> 10253647 2-> 10263748 . See how the nearest points are next to each other? Now you have a 1 dimensional problem! Indexing separately on longitude...

Comment: ... and latitude will help but it won't get you these kinds of efficiencies. See also here: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves for more background.